# Multi-tier complex state machine

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-machine

I'm currently trying to come up with a clean design for coding a multi-tier state machine, and so far, I haven't found the solution in articles about normal state machine usage in C++ or other.

On the very bottom of the hierarchy, we have atomic states: a, b, c, ..., x, y, z.
On top of that, there is a first tier of composite states: A, B, C, D.
Finally, on the very top, there is a final aggregate root state X.

```
       X
    A B C D
a b c d e f g h...
```

In contrast to the usual state machine, the lowest states are defined and determined by external factors; there are no detectable events that change them, changes are detected simply by observing.

Following an atomic state change, he first composite layer has a set of states that it could take, depending on the combination of lower states. For instance: a, b and c are "child"-states of A:

```
a b c - A
0 0 0 - 0
1 0 0 - 1
2 0 0 - x
2 1 0 - 2
```

and so on...where x is undefined.

Finally, the root state has a set of states it can take, based on the composite states - following the same logic as before.

So far, I tried a top-down approach, where the root would call into the sub-states, which in turn would call into the atomic states to update them, cascading back up.

I also tried a bottom-up approach, where the atomic states would update and call up into the sub-states, which in turn would call up into the root state.

In both cases, the fact that a single sub-state might depend on just one or many atomic states makes state verification very convoluted and I end up with non-acceptable, bloated code. I feel like I need a different kind of approach, but I'm stuck on the current design. If anyone has experience with this kind of problem and can offer some inspiration, I would really appreciate.

Comment: have a look at http://www.complang.org/ragel/

Comment: It looks very interesting, but it does not help with this question, as the transition between states are not known - we can only observe state changes after they have happened and adjust the upper tier states based on that.

Comment: you dont know how the transition from one state to the other happens?? i mean, if you are in `state a` and then something happens and then you are in `state A`, you have measured something that marks the current state as `A`. so, there you have your known state-changer .. the thing you observed.

Comment: state a is 1, then it is 2 - there is nothing to track other than let's say a variable that changes. If you will, a is a wrapper around the real state, which we have no access to, other than reading that one variable. Of course, you can arbitrarily decide that each transition from one state to the other is an event, but then you have X times X events, where X is the amount of states. This has two problems, first not all those events will be valid, second, we don't know which ones are valid and which ones are not. This has to be "learned" during execution.

Comment: but you recognize state `1` and state `2`, that is what you measure / observe; that "one variable". next: even an "invalid" state is a state / or an event: it's just an event / state which is labeled "invalid". in your example you can enter any other state from `x`. so, still: look deeper into ragel. you can define the transition actions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One quick thought:**

1) Observer pattern between composite and atomic states ("a", "b", "c" as observees and "A" as observer, so on..)

2) Have class-A implemented using Pimpl idiom to separate the interface & implementation details, thus have more control and exhibit more flexibily in changing the implementation details.

3) Let class-A have some kind of Factory abstraction to create & manage specialized implementation-objects for each unique state of "A".

4) Thus, whenever changes on a, b, c are observed by "A", Factory helps to retrieve the corresponding implementation-state of "A" and does a state change.
Apply same approach between "A" and "X".

**More detailed layout:**

1) Define the required interfaces (generic or abstract classes) IX, IA, Ia, Ib, Ic.

2) In interface IA, define public IaChanged(Ia*), IbChanged(Ib*) & IcChanged(Ic*) methods to receive Ia, Ib & Ic state change notifications (Callback methods of Observer pattern).

3) Inside the atomic interfaces Ia, Ib & Ic. Define public Register(IA&) & private Notify() metods.
In Interface Ia,

```
    Where Notify() { foreach(observer in m_Observers) 
                     observer->IaChanged(this);
                     }
```

In Interface Ib,

```
    Where Notify() { foreach(observer in m_Observers) 
                     observer->IbChanged(this);
                     }
```

so on...

4) Have clases X, A, a, b, c derived from respective interfaces.
   X->IX, A->IA, a->Ia, b->Ib & c->Ic, where -> represents "derives".

5) Have class A define A_implState (Pimpl Idiom), where A_implState may derive from a new interface IA_implState to keep things generic.

Have classes A_implState0, A_implState1, A_implState2, A_implStateX as specialized versions of IA_implState.

where,

```
    class IA_implState
    {
        public:
           virtual void processStateChange()=0;
    };

    class A_implState0 : public IA_implState
    {
        public:
            void processStateChange()
            {
                // do your stuff specific to State "0" of "A".
            }
    };

    class A_implStateX : public IA_implState
    {
        public:
            void processStateChange()
            {
                // do your stuff specific to State "X" of "A".
            }
    };      
    so on...
```

6) Have one specialization of IA_Impl for each distinct states of A, based on:

```
a b c - A
0 0 0 - 0
1 0 0 - 1
2 0 0 - x
2 1 0 - 2
```

7) In class A, whenever IaChanged(IaPtr) or IbChanged(IbPtr) or IcChanged(IcPtr) gets triggered by respective observee, process the change notifications as:

```
   // a changed
    void A::IaChanged(IaPtr a)
    {
     //Buffer Ia inside a member
     m_pIa = a;
     //Retrieve A-implementer based on the current state.
     m_pimplA = m_implAContainer[GetCurrentState()]; // or use FactoryMethod or AbstractFactory pattern if required.
     m_pimplA->processStateChange();
    }

   // b changed
    void A::IbChanged(IbPtr b)
    {
      //Buffer Ib inside a member
      m_pIb = b;
      m_pimplA = m_implAContainer[GetCurrentState()]; // use FactoryMethod or AbstractFactory pattern if required.
      m_pimplA->processStateChange();
    }
```

**/* a rough sketch, may look like */**

use shared_pointers for managing lifetime, define some typedefs for ease of use.

```
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Ia> IaPtr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Ib> IbPtr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<IA_impl> IAImplPtr;
    typedef std::map<int /* or other datatype as required */ , IA_implPtr> ImplAPtrContainer;

    // class-A may look like
    class A : public IA
    {
     public:
      void IaChanged(const IaPtr ptr_a);
      void IbChanged(const IbPtr ptr_b);
      void Init();
      void DeInit() { m_implAContainer.clear(); }

    private:
       int GetCurrentState();

    private:
     ImplAPtrContainer m_implAContainer;
     IAImplPtr m_pimplA;
     IaPtr m_aPtr;
     IbPtr m_bPtr;
     IcPtr m_cPtr;
    };
```

*// Initialize Container with all possible implementation states for class-A*

```
    void A::Init()
    {
      m_implAContainer.insert(/*state*/ 0, IAImplPtr(new A_implState0));
      m_implAContainer.insert(/*state*/ 1, IAImplPtr(new A_implState1));
      m_implAContainer.insert(/*state*/ X, IAImplPtr(new A_implStateX));
    }
```

*// Determine the A's current state based on a, b & c' current state*

```
    int A::GetCurrentState()
    {
        // Have this method return A's state based on a b c, prefer enums over magic numbers
        if(m_aPtr->GetState() == 0 && m_bPtr->GetState() == 0 && m_cPtr->GetState() == 0)
          return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Hey Arun, I will need a while to digest this, but it seems like it could work. At the very least, it will help me take a different approach. If I got it right, you solve the complexity of the state patterns in the Factory method and by having many versions of A?

Comment: Hi Awishformore, if you think factory to be an overkill, have a look at the new edits. It replaces factory with container. Containers are kind of trivial factory and act as lookups. They are preferrable if we have non-mutable, definite and small set of states to handle. Hope this meets your use case.

Comment: I like the approach, however one of the things that bothers me is the requirement for a seperate method for each state change - Iachanged, Ibchanged etc. There will be a lot of atomic states, so it would be preferable to have one generalized method to do it - but then, again, we only know the reference of the state that changed, and not which state is is - I guess using some kind of ID here would do. What do you think?

I also thought about the GetCurrenState() method - how about implementing a hashmap as lookup table? That would enable fast lookup for a huge number of complexe states, right?

Comment: Yup, ID based atomic object passed as a parameter using a generalized callback method definitely reduces the complexity of having separate methods for each atomic state. Also, if the external event is asynchronous in nature(in most cases), this method may have to serialize several atomic changes which might happen at the same time? Also, handling the internal logic of GetCurrentState() using hashing will make things simpler and faster as far as you could generate good hashing function.

Comment: Suppose the atomic state changes are too frequent and asynchronous then it is preferable to shield the frequent updates(unless required by the composite states) using some kind of Proxy. The proxy would sit between the atomic states & the immediate composite state and would serialize the incoming traffic burts from atomic states. Push Model? :)

Comment: Or have the composite state poll for the info from atomic states at frequent intervals. Pull model? U might have to weigh out the pros n cons n decide :)

Comment: Hey Arun. I ended up using one method per atomic state, as generalizing the callback doesn't really work after all. I then use a lookup table with tuples to look the state up. This means that I have to define more concretely what each composite-state looks like (because there will be different tuple sizes for each one), but since there are not that many, it will work fine. The monitor thread calls an update method on the atomic state, which checks if it changed and then calls up into the composite-state method, which looks up its new state in the hashmap. Thanks again for the inspiration :)